# Method reference in Optional.ifPresent() throwing exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Consider the following lines of codes.

```
Object object = "s";
Optional.empty().ifPresent(s -> ((StringBuffer) object).append(s));
Optional.empty().ifPresent(((StringBuffer) object)::append);
```

Functionally, line 2 and line 3 are the same. In fact, in IntelliJ, it suggests that I use method reference for line 2, which would then be exactly the same as line 3. However, when I run the codes with Java 8, line 2 executes fine but line 3 throws a ClassCastException. Obviously, the exception will happen if the codes in ifPresent() are executed, but in both lines 2 and 3, the codes in ifPresent() should not even be executed. So how do we explain the exception happening in line 3?

Comment: The first one only casts if the consumer is executed. The second one casts before `ifPresent` is called. If you want to avoid the cast happening before the consumer is executed, use the first version.

Comment: @khelwood there's only really three things that can happen later as a result of deferring the cast: `ClassCastException`, if `object` isn't of the right type; `NullPointerException`, if `object` is null when you try to invoke `append`; or successful cast and invocation of the method (although things inside that method could also fail). I'd say there could be reasons to choose between, say `s -> foo().append(s)` and `foo()::append`; but I see no good reason to defer a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two aren't the same (and it's a bug in intellij if it suggests this refactoring, at least without explicitly stating the caveat that they have different semantics).

```
Optional.empty().ifPresent(s -> ((StringBuffer) object).append(s));
```

Here, the cast is evaluated when the `Consumer` is executed. It is effectively:

```
Optional.empty().ifPresent(new Consumer<Object>() {
  @Override public void accept(Object s) {
    ((StringBuffer) object).append(s);
  }
});
```

so this will only throw `ClassCastException` if the consumer is invoked.

OTOH

```
Optional.empty().ifPresent(((StringBuffer) object)::append);
```

is effectively:

```
Optional<Object> empty = Optional.empty();
StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer) object;
empty.ifPresent(new Consumer<Object>() {
  @Override public void accept(Object s) {
    sb.append(s);
  }
});
```

Hence, this will throw a `ClassCastException` before the consumer is invoked.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I know very well regarding Optional and method reference, but it turns out that this is another new thing I learned. For the one with method reference, I wonder why it's implemented this way. Why do the cast before the consumer is executed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Optional, per se: it's simply about the semantics of method reference evaluation. In the first case, you're saying "construct the method reference (which happens to do a cast)"; in the second case, you're saying "do a cast, and construct a method reference which invokes a method on the result".

Comment: @user3573403 https://pastebin.com/raw/KuBgvsxK is what gets generated on java 16 (using FernFlower decompiler)